# how to update plotly graph using ajax in django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, plotly

I want to update my plotly graph using ajax in my Django project. This is what I tried so far.
I'm following [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/work-with-ajax-django) guide to doing it and I'm totally new in jquery and ajax.

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),   
    path('smartflow/ajax/updategraph', views.updategraph, name = "updategraph")

]
```

In `views.py` I defined a `updategraph` function(view) to do the job for GET request.

```
def updategraph(request):        
    df_georgian = get it from a csv file for example

    if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
            coding = request.GET.get('coding')

            if coding:
                    trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df_georgian.index,
                                            y=df_georgian.loc[:, df_georgian.columns[2]],
                                            mode='lines',
                                            name='2')


                    fig_new = go.Figure(data=[trace2])
                    plot_div_new = plot(fig_new,
                                            config=config,
                                            output_type='div')

                    data = {
                            'my_data':plot_div_new
                    }
                    return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
            return redirect('smartflow')
```

this is my template:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mx-3 px-0 mt-5 pt-5" id="graph" >
            {% autoescape off %}
            {{ new|safe }}
            {% endautoescape %}
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">

            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="coding" name="interest" value="coding" onclick = "myfunction()">
                <label for="coding">Coding</label>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want, if the `coding` checkbox is selected, then the graph adds the `trace2` to itself and when it is unchecked the `trace2` removes from the existing graphs.

here is my jquery to respond to GET request which is at the end of my template:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $("#coding").change(function () {
    if (document.getElementById('coding').checked) {
        alert("checked");
        
        var current_graph = $('#graph').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'updategraph' %}",
            data: {
                'current_graph': current_graph
            },
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
            // $('#graph').val() = current_graph; //Here is my question?!?!?!?!?!??!?!?!?!
                alert(response);

            }
        });
        
    } else {
        alert("unchecked");
    }
  
});
```

when I select `coding`, I get the following error in the chrome console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/smartflow/ajax/updategraph?current_graph= 500 (Internal Server Error)         jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 
send    @   jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   (index):1683
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:2
v.handle    @   jquery.min.js:2
```

in the success function of my js code ($('#graph').val() = data; //Here is my question?!?!?!?!?!??!?!?!?!) part:

1- I dont know how to get the  `my_data` that I returned in the `views.py` and put it in the div with `#graph` id.

2- how to add the data to the current graph without deleting previous ones.

Comment: Hi , your event will get called when you focusout checkbox not click on submit buttton . Do one thing onces you can check checkbox see your `network tab->XHR` see there `ajax` request details .Also , put `alert(response)` inside success function see if this is showing and what it brings back.

Comment: @Swati you are correct, my event was not right. I updated the question, I also updated the event and tested it with `alert` and it worked just fine, But `alert(response);` shows nothing, does it mean my ajax call is not happening?

Comment: It happen but you have server error . Here , `#graph` is div not input i think you need to pass checkbox value simply get it using `$(this).val()` .Also you are getting value from ajax using `request.GET.get('coding')` .. isn't that should be `request.GET.get('username')` ?

Comment: @Swati the status of the request in `network tab->XHR` is `500`. so my ajax request is not happening, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Swati my bad, I have forgotten to update the variables names. Please check the code again. I used `#graph` to get the current graph and then add the received data from ajax to it. `#coding` is the id of checkbox, is there anything going the be saved in that from ajax call?

Comment: what actually you need to pass to your backend ?

Comment: @Swati I have a data-frame that contains a few columns and I want to plot them. each checkbox is pointing to one of that cols. I want to add the graph of that col to the current graph if the corrosponding checkbox is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225894/discussion-between-swati-and-shahriar-m).

Answer (score 0):

Where you have your comment:

`$('#graph').html(data["current_graph"])`

Answer (score 0):

You can add content to the div using :

```
$('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="theImg.png" />')
```

In this example I am appending an image inside the div..
In the ajax call would be something like :

```
$.ajax({
        url  : "{% url 'url_to_call' %}",
        type : 'get',
        data : {
            somedata : $('#somedata').val()
        },
        success: function(response){
            $( "#the-div" ).prepend('<img id="id" src="theImg.png" />')
        }
    });
```